# Can anyone recommend a free strong and good chess engine for endgame?

Tags: engines

I am looking for good and chess engine for endgame but unfortunately when I test engine with competitive chess players in online,it fails with calculation ability. Please recommend apart from fish family chess engines.Please note I have made ground search in google. thanks for your time

Comment: What's so bad about the fish engines?

Comment: @Annatar. I do not have any conflict with fish family.I love it. I use multiple chess engines in GUI so I already possess fish family thats why thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stockfish with Syzygy 6-man tablebase.

Comment: thanks for immediate answer.I am looking for engine apart from fish family.

Comment: Houdini and Komodo with Syzygy 6-man tablebase... @Ram

Comment: Thanks again for quick answer both are commercial any luck for free and open apart from fish family.

Comment: @Ram: At least one of them offers older versions for free.

Answer (score 0):

Current top engines almost have no problems with endgames, with the exception
of some fortresses, so either one of the best 3 will do just fine.
Years ago it was possible to beat top chess engines even in simple pawn endgames, but not anymore.
Tablebases improve engine play with a small amount of elos, depending on time control and the set used. 5-men would add +5-15 elos, 6-men up to 30, so this is still something, but nothing to marvel at.
7-men would do fine job, but still only commercially available.